# 403 Forbidden Error when I try to pass "param_name=to_char('<date>', '<date_format>')" in URL

Tags: sql, http, url

Generally speaking, I know that passing something with SQL syntax in an URL is a bad idea, but for this instance, I am okay with doing this.  However, I am finding it very difficult to pass a value that looks like `param_name=to_char('<date>', '<date_format>')` in the URL because I immediately get back a 403 (forbidden) error.  I am checking the logs on my Java-enterprise-based application, and nothing on that side is run.  It seems that the web application server itself is blocking these URL's before it even gets to my code.

Is there something wrong with the way that the URL is formed?  Is it perhaps a violation of some URL syntax?

To give you further clarity of what I am dealing with, here is the following response that I get:

```
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 21:25:07 GMT
> Content-Length: 254 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=500 Connection:
> Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

> 403 Forbidden
>
> ## Forbidden
>
> You
>   don't have permission to access /<web_service_path>/<path_parameter>
>   on this server.

Answer (score 0):

When certain reserved characters are used within a URL they must be "percent encoded". The library you're using on the client side probably provides a utility function to do this for you. If you're interested in the gory details, see [RFC 3986.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

- [Section 2.1 "Percent-Encoding"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)
- [Section 2.2, "Reserved Characters"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)
- [Section 2.4, "When to Encode or Decode"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4)

Comment: It would help if you showed the exact request you're sending.

Comment: GET /<web service path>/select.parameterized.snow.code?end_date=to_date('2015-09-25'%2C+'YYYY-MM-DD')&start_date=to_date('2015-09-18'%2C+'YYYY-MM-DD')&_=1443216294272 HTTP/1.1

Comment: `to_date('2015-09-25'%2C+'YYYY-MM-D‌​D')` -- Looks like space is getting encoded as plus, and this is likely confusing something in your stack. Try either removing the space or do whatever is necessary on your client to encode it as %20.

Comment: Removing the space doesn't seem to help